# How to handle Checkbox call inside getView?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am creating a simple application in which showing Items List in custom `ListView` [Item Name, Item Checkbox].

I want to update my UI (showing/hiding `Button` which is not part of ListView but part of Activity containing `ListView` & `Button`) of `Activity` based on Checkbox value change means onCheckChange.

Below is my Adapter class `getView()` method code which calls `Activity` method on list loading which I want to handle.

```
    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                viewHolder = new Holder();
                viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Name);
                viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                        mainDataList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.

            mainDataList.get(position).setLatestChanged(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            activity.setCopyButton(); //This is the call which hides/shows ACTIVITY BUTTON WHICH I WANT TO HANDLE
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.check.setTag(position); // This line is important.
        viewHolder.name.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getName());          

viewHolder.check.setChecked(mainDataList.get(position).isSelected());

            return convertView;
        }
```

On `ListView` loading android it by default calls `viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener` based on ITEM value [T/F]. I have to prevent that call or somehow I want to handle UI update based on manual checkbox click instead of by default.

Trigger point :

```
activity.setCopyButton(); //This is the call which hides/shows activity button which I want to handle
```

Comment: I think you want enable button only when any list item checked right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewHolder.check.setOnCLickListener()` instead.

Replace the following in your code,

```
viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
           //... Your code 
       }
});
```

With this...

```
viewHolder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
        mainDataList.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.

        mainDataList.get(position).setLatestChanged(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        activity.setCopyButton(); //This is the call which hides/shows ACTIVITY BUTTON WHICH I WANT TO HANDLE
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please suggest me changes in the same code instead of making separate because couple of others I am going to link with in upcoming day?

Comment: Already tried out this approach. In this case, getView() calls viewHolder.check.setOnClickListener every time on loading & scroll up/down of list view.

Comment: It should not. You might get the check boxes selected in wrong positions.

Comment: No. As I said earlier some of the items are already checked so by default Checkbox should be checked for them.

Comment: Can you please provide the full adapter code? And please do proper formatting before posting the edit. So it becomes more readable.

Comment: I think getView does all the business logic rest of the methods are as usual so this code is sufficient I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting position as a tag set custom data as tag see the updated code below :-

```
 @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                    viewHolder = new Holder();
                    viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_Name);
                    viewHolder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                   convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                } else {
                    viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
                }

viewHolder.check.setTag(mainDataList.get(position));  
viewHolder.name.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getName());           viewHolder.check.setChecked(mainDataList.get(position).isSelected());
viewHolder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
CustomData data=(CustomData)buttonView.getTag();
data.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); 
data.setLatestChanged(true);
notifyDataSetChanged();
activity.setCopyButton(); 
}
                    });
                return convertView;
            }
```